# Движение объекта в зависимости от его отскока в PyGame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Есть мини-игра, где две платформы и мяч. Реализовать движение мяча по оси X проблем не составляет, но как реализовать движение по оси Y в зависимости от того, как мяч отбился от платформы и от границ экрана?

```
# Creating variables for the game
UPy = WinY // 2 - 162    #UserPlatform Y
UPx = WinX // 6 - 162    #UserPlatfom X
UPySpeed = [WinY / 200, WinY / 150, WinY / 100]    #UserPlatform Y Speed

BallY = WinY // 2 - 40
BallX = WinX // 4 - 40
BallXSpeed = [WinX / 200, WinX / 150, WinX / 100]
BallYSpeed = [WinY / 200, WinY / 150, WinY / 100]

EPy = BallY - 162    #EnemyPlatform Y
EPx = WinX // 3 + WinX // 2 + 120    #EnemyPlatform X

Right = True
Left = False
Up = True
Down = False

ballStart = False

# The game
while gameStart:

    MainSurface = pygame.Surface(WinXY)
    MainSurface.fill((8, 54, 77))

    # Creating platform and ball
    PI = pygame.image.load('data\\platform.png')
    PI.get_rect()
    MainSurface.blit(PI, (UPx, UPy))

    Ball = pygame.image.load('data\\ball.png')
    Ball.get_rect()
    MainSurface.blit(Ball, (BallX, BallY))

    EP = pygame.image.load('data\\platform.png')
    EP.get_rect()
    MainSurface.blit(EP, (EPx, EPy))

    win.blit(MainSurface, (0, 0))

    # Movement of user platform
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and UPy > WinY // 100:
        UPy -= UPySpeed[1]
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and UPy < WinY // 20 + WinY // 2:
        UPy += UPySpeed[1]

    # Ball movement
    for i in range(1):

        # Testing for pushes on screen to initialize ball movement
        for startGame in pygame.event.get():
            if startGame.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] >= WinX // 2 - 50 and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] >= WinY // 2 - 50:
                    if pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] <= WinX // 2 + 50 and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] <= WinY // 2 + 50:
                        ballStart = True

        if ballStart:

            # Changing direction
            if BallX <= UPx + 50 and BallY >= UPy - 80 and BallY <= UPy + 325:
                Right = True
                Left = False

            if Right:
                BallX += BallXSpeed[0]

                pygame.display.update()

            if BallX >= EPx - 80 and BallY >= EPy:
                Left = True
                Right = False

            if Left:
                BallX -= BallXSpeed[0]

                pygame.display.update()

            # Reloading if ball gets out of platforms
            if BallX <= UPx - 40 and BallX >= 0 - 40:
                    BallX = WinX // 4 - 40
                    BallY = WinY // 2 - 40
                    Right = True
                    Left = False
                    ballStart = False
                    break
            elif BallX >= EPx + 45 and BallX <= WinX:
                    BallX = WinX // 4 - 40
                    BallY = WinY // 2 - 40
                    Right = True
                    Left = False
                    ballStart = False
                    break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Должны быть два компонента скорости - vx и vy. На каждом шаге делается обновление обеих координат. При отражении от неподвижной вертикальной стенки меняется знак vx, при отражении от горизонтальной - знак vy.

В приведённом коде уже сделано это для X-компонента, остаётся добавить для Y.

Что такое платформы - они движутся? Учитывается ли отражение от углов?

При отражении от движущейся платформы нормальный компонент скорости инвертируется относительно платформы (т.е. если она движется навстречу шару, то он отскакивает с гораздо большей скоростью). Тангенциальный (продольный) компонент меняется в зависимости от выбранной модели - он может не меняться вовсе, либо - более реалистично - платформа передаёт шару часть продольной скорости.

Comment: В том то и дело, что обе платформы движутся. Отражение от углов делать буду позже, пока первостепенная задача - сделать движение по оси Y с учетом угла, под которым объект отбивается от платформы или границы экрана. Тобишь, как понять, под каким углом двигался объект до отскока, чтобы дать ему такой же угол, но при этом в другом направлении после отскока? Ещё нужно изменять угол движения в зависимости от того, как он будет отскакивать...

Comment: При использовании компонентов вектора скорости угол само по себе и тригонометрию в большинстве случаев можно не рассчитывать. Какая модель отскока будет выбрана? Без кручения мяча, надеюсь?

Comment: Без кручения, само собой. При отскоке мяч будет лишь менять цвет, ну и направление движения

Comment: А будет движущаяся платформа при ударе мяча менять его скорость в продольном направлении?

Comment: А что показать-то? C Y-компонентом и отражением от границ надо сделать по аналогии с X

Comment: Если понадобится найти, с какой стенкой шар столкнётся раньше: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46765161