js canvas игра арканоид. мяч касается угла не разбиваемой платформы и не отскакивает, а прыгает вдоль нее

как сделать чтобы мяч летел в обратную сторону, а не вдоль блоков?
метод удара по платформе
 bumpBlock(block, countBegin, index) {
    this.dy *= -Math.sin(Math.PI / 180 * 15) * this.velocity; //движения мяча по оси У
    if(block.countHits + countBegin == block.isCrashStrikes && block.isCrashStrikes != 0){//проверка на кол-во ударов об платформу мяча
        game.sounds.playSound("blockCrush")
        block.isAlive = false;//удаление блока в случае разбивания
        ++game.score;//добавление очков
    }else{
        block.countHits++ //если блок не разбит записать что по нему был удар
    }
    if (game.score == game.blocks.length - game.isDeadBlock) {
       setTimeout(game.over("Ты выйграл!"),3000) 
    }

}

подскажите как решить проблему?

А что значит - в обратную сторону? Где вы меняете скорость при ударе?

в обратную сторону значит отскочил,
меняю тут не скорость, а направление
this.dy *= -Math.sin(Math.PI / 180 * 15) * this.velocity; а что надо скорость менять?

Что такое направление? При моделировании движении задаётся вектор скорости, на каждый квант времени считается изменение положения https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/915891/291659.   значит отскочил -  отскоков разных типов много бывает...

Могу предоставить код из своего опыта. Там, конечно, физика не шедевр, но отскок реализован хорошо.
